# How to use mp4 file as a Splash screen for my iphone application instead of Default.png

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6

Could any-one please explain me....it's possible in iphone. if yes then could you explain step by step because i am new in iphone development.

Comment: as per my knowledge it's not possible in iPhone or can say for any iOS project.

Comment: and for gif file? it's possible or not??

Comment: Nope it accepts only a .png file type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest you could do would be to have a png image as the splash which contains the 1st frame of the video you want to play and then play a video ASAP.

Some basic code to get you started might look like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                           selector:@selector(playBackDidFinishNotification:)
                                               name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                             object:nil];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

  NSURL *URL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"clip" withExtension:@"m4v"];
  MPMoviePlayerViewController *viewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:URL];

  viewController.moviePlayer.fullscreen = YES;
  viewController.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
  [viewController.moviePlayer play];

  self.window.rootViewController = viewController;

  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}

- (void)playBackDidFinishNotification:(NSNotification *)notification;
{
  self.window.rootViewController = [[PSRootViewController alloc] init];
}
```

Comment: what is PSRootViewController on it??